# Как красиво проверить на 0 и прибавить, или присвоить 1

Tags: c++

Мне нужно сделать это, только как то красиво и минималистично, но скобки не трогайте они нужны.

Вариант 1

```
int test = 0;

if(!test) {
   test = 1;

}
```

Вариант 2

```
if(test == 0) {
   test = 1;
}
```

Вариант 3

```
if(test == 0) {
   test++;
}
```

идея такая нужны скобки обязательно

```
а тут должно быть все что нужно
{

}
```

мне не нравится что приходиться писать `test = 1;` внутри скобок. А так вроде все норм.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112340/discussion-on-question-by-nuxt-----0----).

Comment: Ассемблерной вставкой :)

Answer (score 2):

`if(!test) { test = 1; }` — абсолютно нормальная форма. Именно её следует использовать IRL.

Но если хочется бессмысленного изощрения, то вот несколько способов:

```
test = test ? test : 1;

test == 0 ? (test = 1) : 0;

test || test++;

test += !test;

switch (test) {
    case 0: ++test;
}
```

---

<sub>Ответ общий — правьте смело</sub>